# Infinite animation of an object flying a path using CSS3

Tags: css, css-animations

Good day, there was the task to make the animation of an airplane flying around a path. I decided to take advantage of the opportunities in CSS3. But all I have achieved is one animation cycle. The plane flies one circle around the path and the animation stops. I tried using `animation-iteration-count` with `infinite`, but all I got was the flight of a plane in chaotic directions. Below is my code, please tell me how to loop this animation so that the plane constantly flies in a circle without stopping.

### Code

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 100px;
}

.route {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 3px dotted #000;
  position: relative;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
  left: 100%;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  animation: flyLeft 1.5s linear forwards, rotatePlane 0.5s linear 1.5s forwards, flyUp 1s linear forwards 2s, RotateRight 0.5s linear 2.8s forwards, MoveRight 3s linear forwards 3s, RotateDown 1s linear 6s forwards, flyDown 1s linear forwards 7s, RotateLeft 1s linear 7.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes flyLeft {
  100% {
    left: -14px;
  }
}

@keyframes rotatePlane {
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flyUp {
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes RotateRight {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes MoveRight {
  0% {
    left: -14px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 380px;
  }
}

@keyframes RotateDown {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(270deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flyDown {
  0% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: -8%;
  }
}

@keyframes RotateLeft {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="route">
    <img class="plane" src="http://p36099-290-14699.s290.upress.link/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/plane.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is not a "circle"...I assume you mean you want the animation to loop around the border.

Comment: I would suggest you combine those animations into a single set of key-frames unless you're planning on reusing them.

Comment: Indeed. you can't use "infinite" on a **series** of keyframe animations

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake I really meant the path, not a circle.

Comment: Is the path always going to be a rectangular box?

Comment: Yes, the path always going to be a rectangular box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap all the animations in one `@keyframes` CSS at-rules to easily make repetitions. Here's a working solution below that wraps all the animations in one `@keyframes`.

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 100px;
}

.route {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 3px dotted #000;
  position: relative;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  animation: travelRoundTheBorder 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes travelRoundTheBorder {
  30% {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  }
  
  32.5% {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(90deg);
  }
  
  47.5% {
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(90deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  80% {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  82.5% {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(270deg);
  }
  
  97.5% {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(270deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="route">
    <img class="plane" src="http://p36099-290-14699.s290.upress.link/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/plane.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: True but it's not very smooth on the turns.

Comment: @Paulie_D You just need to adjust the timing function (the percentage) for the turn. How long (in ms) do you want a turn to be?

Comment: Thanks so much, css3 animation is new area for me and I would spend a lot of time to solve this task. Thanks to you, I understood and can use it to solve other typical tasks with css3 animation.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've adjusted it to take .25s for each turn.

Comment: @VictorSokoliuk Sure, I've adjusted it to be faster. Do try playing around with the percentages and the values inside the keyframes to see how they work.

Comment: @Richard Yes, I will. It will be useful for me to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the movement along the path and the turns into TWO separate keyframes makes this easier.

The math of the percentages is based on a **square** but with a rectangle the percentages change.

CSS variable could help here to work out those percentages but I haven't gone deeper into that for the demo purposes.

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 10px;
}

.route {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px dotted #000;
  position: relative;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: path 6s linear infinite, turn 6s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes path {
  0%,
  100% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes turn {
  0%,
  24% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  25%,
  49% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(270deg);
  }
  50%,
  74% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  75%,
  99% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="route">
    <img class="plane" src="http://p36099-290-14699.s290.upress.link/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/plane.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. That's cool. The fact that I tried to decide the day you do in a few minutes. Health and blessings to you and your families.

Answer (score 1):

Just to begin testing new CSS posibilities, offset-path (not supported in IE, experimental in FF)

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path)

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: dotted 5px black;
  margin: 30px;
    
}

#motion-demo {
  offset-path: path('M0 -10 H400 A 10 10 1 0 1 410 0 V300 A 10 10 1 0 1 400 310 H0 A 10 10 1 0 1 -10 300 V0');
  animation: move 10s infinite linear;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: cyan;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="motion-demo">A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's really an awesome function. I've just read it through and see that the offset-path function has many ways to use.